# Multiple TextView in ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` with two `TextView` that fill from `DataBase` but show me just one `row` :

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public static final String DIR_SDCARD =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
public static final String DIR_DATABASE = DIR_SDCARD +"/Android/data/";
EditText editText;
DB db = new DB(MainActivity.this);
public String Titel_Drawer;
public String Titel_Drawert;
public String messageCursor;
public SQLiteDatabase  sql;
public Cursor cursor;
public Cursor cursort;
public ArrayList<String> array;
public ArrayList<String> arrayt;
public static String PACKAGE_NAME;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        File file= new File(DIR_DATABASE + PACKAGE_NAME + "/DB");
        file.mkdirs();
        db.GetPackageName(PACKAGE_NAME);
        db.CreateFile();
        try {
            db.CreateandOpenDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sql = db.openDataBase();
        cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT Comment FROM WebSite_MetaDataDBBack", null);
        cursort = sql.rawQuery("SELECT Title FROM WebSite_CategoryBack", null);
        array = new ArrayList<String>();
           if(cursor!=null)
            {
                if(cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do {
                        Titel_Drawer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Comment"));
                        array.add(Titel_Drawer);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
           cursor.close();
           arrayt = new ArrayList<String>();
           if(cursort!=null)
            {
                if(cursort.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do {
                        Titel_Drawert = cursort.getString(cursort.getColumnIndex("Title"));
                        arrayt.add(Titel_Drawert);
                    } while (cursort.moveToNext());
                }
            }
           cursort.close();
        final List<Contact> listOfContact = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        listOfContact.add(new Contact(Titel_Drawert,Titel_Drawer));
        ContactAdapter ConAdapter = new  ContactAdapter(this,listOfContact);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
        list.setAdapter(ConAdapter);
}
}
```

Here is my `get` and `set` in Contact.java:

```
public class Contact {
    private String title;
    private String description;

    public Contact(String title, String description) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

And here is ContactAdapter.java :

```
public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
    private Context context;

    private List<Contact> listContact;

    public ContactAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> listContact) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listContact = listContact;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return listContact.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listContact.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Contact entry = listContact.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_layout_main, null);
        }
        TextView tvContact = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView_Main);
        tvContact.setText(entry.getTitle());

        TextView tvPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView_Main2);
        tvPhone.setText(entry.getDescription());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp">
    </ListView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

My drawer_layout_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowTextView_Main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowTextView_Main2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Include your layout file - also - check to ensure the the Array you are setting your adapter has multiple values (determine if your array is set right, or if you have issues with your layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your listOfContact only has 1 item:

```
final List<Contact> listOfContact = new ArrayList<Contact>();
listOfContact.add(new Contact(Titel_Drawert,Titel_Drawer));
ContactAdapter ConAdapter = new  ContactAdapter(this,listOfContact);
```

So your getCount() returns 1.

```
public int getCount() {
    return listContact.size();
}
```

Replace your listContact in the adapter with a List that has one element for each item you want a row for.